# upload an image and a label with Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I am toying around with an image uploader using Flask. I cloned it from this repository https://github.com/chokepoint/flaskgur . I have it running on my VPS here

```
http://107.170.119.38
```

What I'm trying to do is enable someone to write a custom label for an image they are about to upload. The final product should display an image and the custom label the user typed in. The image uploader works fine but I can't seem to store the label in the database on upload. Here is my code

```
from flask import Flask, request, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template,send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from hashlib import md5
from PIL import Image
import sqlite3
import os
import time

DEBUG              = True
BASE_DIR           = '/var/www/flaskgur/'
UPLOAD_DIR         = BASE_DIR + 'pics'
DATABASE           = BASE_DIR + 'flaskgur.db'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# Make sure extension is in the ALLOWD_EXTENSIONS set
def check_extension(extension):
    return extension in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

# Return a list of the last 25 uploaded images  
def get_last_pics():
    cur = g.db.execute('select * from pics order by id desc limit 25')
    filenames = [dict(id=row[0], filename=row[1], label=row[2]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    #filenames = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return filenames

# Insert filename into database 
def add_pic(filename, label):
    g.db.executemany('insert into pics (filename, label) values (?, ?)', [filename, label])
    g.db.commit()

# Generate thumbnail image
def gen_thumbnail(filename):
    height = width = 200
    original = Image.open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'], filename))
    thumbnail = original.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumbnail.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'], 'thumb_'+filename))


def add_label(label):
    label = request.form['label']
    g.db.execute('INSERT INTO pics (label) VALUES (?)', [label])
    g.db.commit()


# Taken from flask example app
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()

# Taken from flask example app
@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    db = getattr(g, 'db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_pic():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        try:
            extension = file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
        except IndexError, e:
            abort(404)
        if file and check_extension(extension):
            # Salt and hash the file contents
            filename = md5(file.read() + str(round(time.time() * 1000))).hexdigest() + '.' + extension
            file.seek(0) # Move cursor back to beginning so we can write to disk
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'], filename, label))
            add_pic(filename)
            add_label(label)
            gen_thumbnail(filename)
            return redirect(url_for('show_pic', filename=filename))
        else: # Bad file extension
            abort(404)
    else:
        return render_template('upload.html', pics=get_last_pics())

@app.route('/show')
def show_pic():
    filename = request.args.get('filename','')
    return render_template('upload.html', filename=filename, label=label)
def show_label():
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('SELECT label FROM pics WHERE id=(?)')
    labels = cur.fetchone()
    return render_template('upload.html', labels=labels)

@app.route('/pics/<filename>')
def return_pic(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'], secure_filename(filename))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

And my template (upload.html):

```
{% if filename is defined %}
    <div id="image"><a href="{{ pic_path(filename) }}" target="_blank"><img class="new" src="{{ pic_path(filename) }}"></a></div>

        <h2><p>The Label is: </p>{{ labels }}</h2>


{% else %}
    <ul>
    {% for pic in pics %}
        <li class="thumb"><a href="{{ url_for('show_pic', filename=pic) }}"><img class="thumb" src="{{ pic_path('thumb_'+pic) }}"></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

base template (base.html):

```
    <div id="upload">
        <h1>Upload Picture</h1>
        <form action="/" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <p>
            <input type=file name=file><br />
            <p>Add a Label:</p>
            <input type=text name=label value={{ request.form.label }}><br />
            <input type=submit value=Upload>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I apologize if my code is atrocious. I am trying my best to learn

Comment: Your `add_pic` function only gets a `filename` so the `label` variable you use in your SQL statement is never set.

Comment: Still not working :/

Comment: can you amend your question to include your updated code and the code that handles the form data and calls the add_pic function?

Comment: I've amended it to include all my code.

Comment: Your `upload_pic` function never reads the label information from the form. I'd expect to see a `label = request.form['label']` in there.

Comment: yeah I added that below file = request.files['file'] and still no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Rewrote the get_last_pics() function to this:

```
# Return a list of the last 25 uploaded images
def get_last_pics():
try:
    cur = g.db.execute('select filename, label from pics order by id desc limit 25')
    filenames = []
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        filenames.append({"filename": row[0], "label": row[1] or ''})
    return filenames
except:
    return []
```

rewrote add_pic() to this:

```
# Insert filename and label into database
def add_pic(filename, label):
g.db.execute('insert into pics (filename, label) values (?, ?)', [filename, label])
g.db.commit()
```

rewrote upload_pic() to this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_pic():
if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.files['file']
    label = request.form['label']
    try:
        extension = file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
    except IndexError, e:
        abort(404)
    if file and check_extension(extension):
        # Salt and hash the file contents
        filename = md5(file.read() + str(round(time.time() * 1000))).hexdigest() + '.' + extension
        file.seek(0)  # Move cursor back to beginning so we can write to disk
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'], filename))
        add_pic(filename, label)
        gen_thumbnail(filename)
        return redirect(url_for('show_pic', filename=filename))
    else:
        # Bad file extension
        abort(404)
else:
    return render_template('upload.html', pics=get_last_pics())
```

rewrote show_pic() to this:

```
@app.route('/show')
def show_pic():
filename = request.args.get('filename', '')
t = (filename,)
cur = g.db.execute('select label from pics where filename=?', t)
label = cur.fetchone()[0]

return render_template('upload.html', filename=filename, label=label)
```

Everything works now. Hope that helps someone in the future

Comment: Cheers, mate. Have some upvotes. I was following along with your examples.

Comment: Wow feels great to actually help someone here for once!